# What is the purpose of caches?

Tags: caching

I was wondering why caches exist. As a Drupal newbie, I often read solutions for all kind of problems that mention "you have to clear caches". Therefore, it appears to me that they only have disadvantages. This may sound a bit naive, but I would like to know what their purpose is.

Comment: Imagine a car. Gas can run out. Oil needs to be changed. Cooling liquid can freeze. Nothing of this would happen without an engine, so engines in cars have only disadvantages, right? But you want it anyway, to go faster. Now, do you know what cache is, generally in IT? See [Cache (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Actually, I didn't know what caching is, to be honest. Thanks for the link and the car example. It would fit as an answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching decrease your page load time and speed up your site. It is used especially when you have images, maps, videos and audio on your page. We can use drupal internal cache or integrate other caching tools like APC, Mem Cache, Varnish with our drupal site.

**Why we clear cache?**
 When we made some new changes in our theme or code, so to test them we clear old cache so that old data will be removed from cache and new data will be loaded to be displayed changes.

Answer (score 0):

For a very beginner guide to caching and why it's helpful try [this link](http://blog.merge.nl/20120118/how-does-caching-work-drupal)

and if you still wanna get a little (just a little) more into it try [this Lullabot article](http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/beginners-guide-caching-data-drupal-7)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: true story! I'll edit the answer soon

Comment: I have just rediscovered this old question of mine. How naive I was... However, what about the "soon" edit you promised to @mpdonadio?